# Python click and --help option callback isn't eager

Tags: python, python-click

I have the following click code:

```py
@click.group(invoke_without_command=True)
def cli():
    click.echo("Starting CallFlow....")
    setup_logging()


# ##################----GEN---##################
@cli.command(help="a sub command")
@click.option(
    "--folder", help="Tests folder path", type=str, nargs=1,
)
def sub1(folder):
    # run some code here
```

Running my prog name that uses the above cli like this:

```sh
prog-name --help
```

shows me the correct help text:

```sh
Usage: prog-name [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...

Options:
  --help  Show this message and exit.

Commands:
  sub1       Help text
```

But running

```sh
prog-name sub1 --help --folder
```

I get an error that folder requires an argument like so:

```sh
Error: --folder option requires an argument
```

I thought that --help was an eager parameter and gets evaluated first. shouldn't that produce a help text?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/options/#callbacks-and-eager-options), the concept of eagerness refers only to the order of execution. Usually, the command line options will be processed in the order they are defined; making options like `--help` and `--version` eager means that they will be evaluated first.

If `--help` were not eager, your example would require `--folder` to always be passed first, like:

```
prog-name sub1 --folder test_folder --help
```

Comment: So I am guessing there is no way to make `--help` override any other command given. e.g if I run `git remote add -t` I get `error: switch -t requires a value` but If I run `git remote add -t --help` overrides the `-t` and shows the help menu

Comment: If the other options provided are not valid, e.g. `--folder` without a value, then it seems click will raise an error regardless of the ordering with `--help`

Comment: To my understanind the order of execution means that --help is executed first, as eager options. So it should show --help and exit right?

Comment: It appears that validation of all command line parameters (is the value present?) may take precedence

Comment: So if you need that kind of behaviour you need to do that manually